# MySQL ORDER BY: different EXPLAIN for SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, sql-order-by, mariadb

Please consider a table with `queue_name`, `priority` and `message_timestamp` columns.

Here is a compound index for that:

```
CREATE INDEX STATE_QUEUENAME_PRIORITY_TIMESTAMP ON
       `queue_messages` (queue_name, state, priority, message_timestamp);
```

EXPLAIN for SELECT:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  message_timestamp
        from    queue_messages
        WHERE   queue_name = 'folder'
            AND state = 0
        ORDER BY priority DESC, message_timestamp DESC 
                 LIMIT 1;
```

Returns `Using where; Using index`

EXPLAIN for UPDATE (with the same `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`!):

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE  queue_messages
        SET     state = 1
        WHERE   queue_name = 'folder'
            AND state = 0
        ORDER BY priority DESC, message_timestamp DESC
                 LIMIT 1;
```

Returns `Using where; Using filesort`

--

It causes significant performance impact (20ms SELECT vs 90ms UPDATE on 50k rows).

How can I force MariaDB (MySQL) to get rid of `filesort` in UPDATE statement?

Comment: You could try giving an Index Hint https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I don't know for sure but you are updating state which is part of the key so maybe you can't.

Comment: Is that the only index?

Comment: PS: Why do you bother with `ORDER BY` in an update? (And why does MySql even allow it?)

Comment: @P.Salmon Just tried to update non-key column. Unfortunately result is the same

Comment: @CraigYoung Also I have auto index for compound PK (queue_name, message_id). I bother with order by because I need to update only top N rows using sort by given columns

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tryied that: `EXPLAIN UPDATE queue_messages USE INDEX (PRIMARY, STATE_QUEUENAME_PRIORITY_TIMESTAMP) SET weight = 1 WHERE queue_name = '1.folder.1' AND state = 0 ORDER BY priority DESC, message_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;` Unfortunately it's still slow, and `EXPLAIN` returns `Using where; Using filesort`

Comment: @silent-box Ok. I missed the `LIMIT` right at the end. I'm not sure why mysql plans the queries differently. However, I do suggest you'd be better off in any case keying your updates by PK. This shouldn't suffer the problem you're experiencing. But more importantly your current approach has potential for insidious bugs because the update statement is not deterministic. It doesn't consistently affect a predetermined message, but on each execution determines which message to update based on current data. This is much more difficult to reason about in a multi-user system.

Comment: @CraigYoung Thank you for this information. Actually the table we talking about is basically a queue from which I'm trying to poll the oldest message (update the state) for processing. RDBMS does not sound like a good solution for that, but unfortunately I have to use it for some non-tech reasons. Trying to find the most efficient way. So the next bunch of updates always will be non-deterministic because of different sorting and batch size. I can't find another way, but open for any suggestions.

Comment: Historically, `SELECT` and `UPDATE` have been handled differently.  There was some change recently in the processing; what version are you running?  Meanwhile, please file a bug report with either bugs.mysql.com or mariadb.com .  (or both if you tested both)

Comment: @RickJames Ok, thank you. I'm running latest MariaDB 10.1.22, same result on latest MySQL 5.7.17

Answer (score 0):

For the `update`, you need a second index:

```
CREATE INDEX STATE_QUEUENAME_TIMESTAMP_2 ON `queue_messages` (queue_name, state, priority, message_timestamp);
```

Your existing index doesn't include `priority`, so it cannot be used for the `order by`.

Comment: I am very sorry, I accidentely copy-paste the wrong index declaration. You are right, and I already use an index with all 4 fields. Updated the question with the correct index: `STATE_QUEUENAME_PRIORITY_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Actually that's why I am wondering - SELECT query matches index perfectly, but UPDATE with absolutely same WHERE/ORDER clauses - not.